# Different Behavior of moveMouseEvent on different Widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

While studying Event Handling I noticed mouseMoveEvent and implemented it on QTextBrowser and QPushButton and the results were different in a manner.When I hover aroung QTextBrowser mouseMoveEvent got activated.But in case of QPushButton the mouseMove event occured when mouse remain clicked and then cursor hover around.As soon as click is released hovering on Button has no effect.
Why there is such differece?and what should I do to so as to achieve the same functionality on QPushButton i.e. activating event without mouseKeypressed

```
class window35(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window35, self).__init__()
        myWidget=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Hbox=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("HAA BHYI\nBUTTON")
        self.textBrowser=QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.Hbox.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        myWidget.setLayout(self.Hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(myWidget)
        self.btn.mouseMoveEvent=self.mouse_move
        self.textBrowser.mouseMoveEvent=self.text_browser_move
#        print(type(self.btn.mouseMoveEvent))

        self.show()
    def mouse_move(self,event):
        print("hello btn")
        try:
            QtWidgets.QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(self.btn,event)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)

    def text_browser_move(self,event):
        print("hello list")
        try:
            QtWidgets.QTextBrowser.mouseMoveEvent(self.textBrowser,event)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)




app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ex=window35()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I noticed listWidget also worked Like QPushButton
Thanks :)

Comment: Not all widget types have [mouse tracking enabled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G.M. 
I just added

```
self.btn.setMouseTracking(True)
```

to achieve the desired effect